# Unable to find "Opportunity" class in SFDC (SalesForce)

Tags: java, classpath, salesforce

SalesForce Opportunity example at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm#topic-title uses "Opportunity" class to begin with.

For some reason I'm not able to find this class (or any Standard SalesForce classes) in the classpath at all. I'm able to find others classes though e.g. "com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject"

Any ideas or help will be very useful.

Thanks in advance
-a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've imported the partner WSDL, which is a loosely typed API, and doesn't include any concrete types (like Opportunity). The sample code is for the enterprise API, which provides a strongly typed API, including all the standard objects and your customizations, you need to import the enterprise WSDL instead for that example.